# Can a SQL Server trigger use more than one process and possibly deadlock itself? Troubleshooting a deadlock

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2016, deadlock

I have a table called TableA and another table called TableB. Both have Customerid column in them.

TableA has an after trigger which has this in it (simplified SQL):

```
Delete from TableB where CustomerId = (Select CustomerId from inserted)
Insert into TableB Select * from ViewX where CustomerId = (Select CustomerId from inserted)
```

ViewX is a view that reads from several tables joined, one of them is TableA.

I am getting sometimes deadlocks and when I analyze the deadlock information from sp_readerrorlog, I see that the victim process has the trigger's Delete statement and another process with the trigger's Insert statemen. Two processes with two different IDs (shown below). Can a trigger be using more than one process for its statements?

When I look at the resource-list, shown below, I am not sure if this means its two updates for TableA for two different customers are executed at the same time and the same page is locked? or the trigger deadlocked itself. 
I see the same SQL Update statement right beneath the inputbuf line for each process with parameters but the values for the parameters are not shown therefore I can't figure out if it's the same update statement or two different updates. I am also looking for a better way to do this.

process17428c6fc28 is the delete statement and process29bdcd8b468 is the insert statement.

```
resource-list
   keylock hobtid=72057595429978112 dbid=8 objectname=TableB indexname=idx_someindex id=lock2c954a4d880 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057595429978112
    owner-list
     owner id=process29bdcd8b468 mode=X
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process17428c6fc28 mode=U requestType=wait
   pagelock fileid=1 pageid=23599080 dbid=8 subresource=FULL objectname=TableC  id=lock2cb3a1a3900 mode=IX associatedObjectId=72057595164557312
    owner-list
     owner id=process17428c6fc28 mode=IX
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process29bdcd8b468 mode=S requestType=convert
```

Comment: Two separate connections updating a table in a way that fires the trigger might make the trigger cause a dead lock with itself. Technically the dead locks are on tables or indexes referenced by the trigger.

Comment: Can a trigger be using more than one process for its statements? No, if it were possible it would mean that delete (which is before the insert) would execute in parallel with the insert (which is after the delete): two statements in the same batch executing in parallel.

Comment: @richard crossley. I don't get what you said. If there are two connections then there are two separate processes. Then how would a trigger deadlock itself if there two separate connections?

Comment: @Abdu A single invocation of a trigger will not deadlock itself. A trigger called by multiple processes may.